# get indexPath for customCell in TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITextField` in a `customCell`. I want to be able to get the text that user inputs in it. In my customCell.m file I can get the text that is inputed with

```
[self.aTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(aTextFieldEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

but I cannot get the `indexPath` so I can save it to the `NSMutableArray` that holds all the `UITextField`s.

In my `TableView` I cannot get the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to run. I also cannot get the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method to output anything. If it helps I have a `TableView` with sections.

My idea at the moment is to get the `indexpath.row` and `indexpath.section` from the `tableView` and save them as an extern so I can access it in the customCell.m

I would be grateful for any ideas or specific examples of how I could do this. Or a different cleaner way to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the index path using the `-indexPathForRowAtPoint:` method on `UITableView`.

You can do something like this (not tested):

```
- (void)aTextFieldEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    CGPoint convertedPoint = [textField.superview convertPoint:textField.center toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:convertedPoint];
    // Use your index path...
}
```

Edit:

In the case your cell is receiving the edit events, you can always define a protocol and make your view controller a delegate of the cell. You could then call this delegate method from your `aTextFieldEditing` method and pass the cell. Now that you have the cell you can call `-indexPathForCell` on your table view. If none of this makes sense, look into the delegate pattern. It's very common in Cocoa/Cocoa Touch and is very well documented online.

Comment: I tried what you said but self doesn't have a tableView. I think its because `aTextFieldEditing:` is in the customCell.m file. I tried using UITableView *tableV = (UITableView *)[textField superview]; and then plugging it in but my program crashed.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll check out the documentation on protocols and delegates. Then I'll hopefully be able to report back and mark your response as the correct answer. :)